# Getting variable then dynamically updating another variable elsewhere

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button where if I click it takes the name of the button and inputs it into a public method on a script elsewhere, here is the .xmal for the button and .cs file behind it:

.xaml file:

```
<Button Width="180"
                         Name="apple"
                         Height="180"
                         Margin="10,0,0,10"
                         Style="{StaticResource FoodOptionTheme_YO}"
                         Content="Apple" 
                         Click="On_Click_Add"/>
```

Code:

```
private readonly Food_Calculations _value;

       public FoodsView()
       {
           _value = new Food_Calculations();
           InitializeComponent();
           
       }
       
       private void On_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           _value.Calc(Name);
       }
```

I then take that input in Calc() method in this script:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private int[] _total = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        private string total = "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0";

        private void OnPropertyChanged(String property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public void Calc(string value)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int[]> arraysDic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
            {
                {"apple", apple },
                {"pear", pear },
                {"banana", banana },

            };

            if (arraysDic.ContainsKey(value))
            {
                int[] current = arraysDic[value];
                for (int i = 0; i < current.Length; i++)
                {
                    _total[i] = current[i];
                }
                total = string.Join(" ", _total);
            }
        }

        public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                return total;
            }
            set
            {
                total = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }
```

And take the input and display it in another view, here's the code and the .xaml for this view:

.xmal file:

```
<TextBlock Name="resultsText"
                   FontSize="40"
                   Panel.ZIndex="2"
                   Foreground="White">
            <Run Text="Result"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding textData}"/>
        </TextBlock>
```

Code:

```
        {
            string value = new Food_Calculations().Result;
            InitializeComponent();
            resultsText.DataContext = new TextboxText() { textData = value };
        }
```

My problem is that when I click the button the texblock doesn't update and I'm not sure where the problem is, I tried printing to the console at different points but nothing happened. Would love some help if anyone knows where my problem is, thank you.

Comment: Your two views use different instances of the Food_Calculations() class. Your changes to First view will not be reflected in second view because they are different instances. How are these views related ? Do you have a database ?

Comment: I have each view in a resource dictionary each in its on data template, I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to all this how would I put them in a database?

Comment: No problem. I was just asking to see what your project infrastructure is.  More specifically, if you had to calculate and save information in database. Are you using MVVM / and MVVM frameworks perchance ? Sending data between views becomes easier if you are using some frameworks.

Comment: I'm been trying to figure it out and I've managed to get somewhere but when I click the button it doesn't update and I was wondering if I had to use something like UpdateSourceTriggers but I don't where I would implement it. To answer your question: I have an MVVM folder with Views, ViewModels my Script and my Themes but otherwise I haven't found any MVVM framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong DataContext, hadn't set any of m classes in other scripts public and wasn't using INotifyPropertyChanged in the way i should have been, works now. :)